# Is it possible to contribute a native speaker for editing the paper and add him/her as authors? Is there anyone?

Tags: publications, computer-science, editors, code, grammar

I'm working on SIMDization and Optimization. I usually do some great jobs. But writing a good article needs a good knowledge of writing skill. I've implemented many programs. I can write and organize the paper. But editing the article take a lot of time for me, because of some silly grammatical mistakes. I just thought it might be possible to contribute someone who knows English well and add him/her name as the second author. Is It a good Idea? If yes how can I find someone? Preferred from Toronto Ontario.

Comment: So ... you want someone you don't know and is not at all familiar with your work to proofread and edit your paper for free ... respectively for appearing as an author? First, this person won't fit the definition of authorship. Second, if it's not one of your close colleagues where you already implemented a give and take, you should/have to pay for the proofreading.

Comment: I meant to find someone who is interested in researching especially my field as a coworker. Not only edit the paper for free and add the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may vary in some ways by field, but it is generally not considered sufficient for an individual to be included as an author on a paper if that person's sole contribution to the paper is proofreading and editing. Readers, reviewers, and journal editors expect that each author has made a significant technical contribution to the material presented in the paper. If there isn't a monetary payment involved, credit to someone for editing a paper usually takes the form of written thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you find yourself unable to spend money on editing services by publishers (in chemistry I know only about them by [ACS](http://es.acschemworx.acs.org/en/editing/) or [Wiley](http://wileyeditingservices.com/en/)) or local proof readers (like this example in [Toronto](https://editfast.com/english/editors/Canada-CAN/Ontario/Toronto-city.htm) lists 33 names/contacts) maybe there are programmers you know (because their work inspired you, or/and will be cited by you) you may reach out.

Or --- relating in analogy to R, Python, Emacs --- contacting a local usergroup (like this about [C++](https://www.meetup.com/Toronto-CPP-User-Group/)) of a programming language / software you use is an alternative; in contrast to an English student at the university they already know the technical terms of your field, and you could pay them not only by money.